How a B2C identity matches a Dynamics Contact in Power Pages Site
My Power Pages Sites uses Azure AD B2C for authentication. I would like to know how a B2C identity matches a Dynamics Contact. I found a very good blog: https://community.dynamics.com/blogs/post/?postid=1dd4444c-2602-4600-b34e-736b2be52b75. It said the matching is between the email claim in the B2C token and the email in the contact's "primary email address" field.
First, I cannot find the "primary email address" field of the contact. Would it be emailaddress1 instead? I deliberately changed the emailaddress1 to something else, yet I can still sign in with the same B2C identity.
